# Изменение контента страницы при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть такой сайт: https://granola.com.ua/ и в нём при прокрутке меняется содержимое страницы. Только не могу понять, каким образом реализовывается смена контента, сайт 100% длины, pageYOffset в данном случае не работает, что логично... Есть какие-то идеи/ответы?)

Comment: есть событие `wheel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует событие `mousewheel`, которое применяется к любому элементу, над которым происходит скролл. У объекта event в обработчике этого события также есть свойство `wheelDelta`, которое хранит отрицательное число, если прокрутка идет вниз, и положительное, если вверх.
То бишь, нужно просто отлавливать это событие, предварительно выставив странице `overflow: hidden`, и менять в обработчике контент страницы

Comment: И да, `mousewheel` - это более кроссбраузерная версия `wheel`

Comment: более кроссбраузерная? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event

Comment: Ого, спасибо за информацию. Не знал